# Dart metadata annotation without the prefixed @ atsign?

Tags: flutter, dart, annotations, metadata

As per the Dart [documentations](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#metadata):

> A metadata annotation begins with the character `@`, followed by either
> a reference to a compile-time constant (such as `deprecated`) or a call to a constant constructor.

Nevertheless, consider the following excerpt [from the Flutter source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/tap.dart#L159):

```
@protected
void handleTapDown({ required PointerDownEvent down });
//                   ^^^^^^^^
```

If it's a metadata annotation, then why it doesn't begin with the prefixed `@` sign? If it's not, then what is it?!

Comment: New keyword that is being introduced by the upcoming null safety feature: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days (before Dart 2.12 - null safety), the current `required` keyword was the `@required`  metadata annotation.

> If it's a metadata annotation, then why it doesn't begin with the
> prefixed @ sign? If it's not, then what is it?!

`required` is *not* a metadata annotation, it's a [*Dart keyword*](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#keywords), which means that it's one of the words that Dart treats specially.

---

So, what's the difference? Citing from the [Dart documentation, Null safety FAQs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#how-does-required-compare-to-the-new-required-keyword):

> The `@required` annotation marks named arguments that must be passed; if
> not, the analyzer reports a hint.
>
> With null safety, a named argument with a non-nullable type must
> either have a default or be marked with the new `required` keyword.
> Otherwise, it wouldn’t make sense for it to be non-nullable, because
> it would default to null when not passed.
>
> When null safe code is called from legacy code the `required` keyword is
> treated *exactly* like the `@required` annotation: failure to supply the
> argument will cause an analyzer hint.
>
> When null safe code is called from null safe code, failing to supply a
> required argument is an error.
>
> What does this mean for migration? Be careful if adding `required` where
> there was no `@required` before. Any callers not passing the
> newly-required argument will no longer compile. Instead, you could add
> a default or make the argument type nullable.